# Flex: Custom ProgressBar bar skin won't fill entire track

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, progress-bar, skinning

I'm trying to create a simple skin for the flex progressbar control. Both the track and the bar should have rounded corners, and the bar should fill the track completely in the parts where it is being shown.

Here is the bar skin I've created based off [this example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/04/13/creating-a-custom-bar-skin-on-an-mx-progressbar-control-in-flex-4/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        override protected function initializationComplete():void {
            useChromeColor = true;
            super.initializationComplete();
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Rect radiusX="5" radiusY="5" top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0">
        <s:fill>            
            <s:SolidColor color="#bb0203" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

</s:SparkSkin>
```

Here is the progress bar declaration:

```
<mx:ProgressBar id="progressBar" name="progressBar" top="40" left="10" width="480" height="25"
    label="" labelWidth="0"
    trackSkin="Skins.ProgressBar.TrackSkin"
    barSkin="Skins.ProgressBar.BarSkin" />
```

And here is the track skin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    minHeight="25">

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        override protected function initializationComplete():void {
            useChromeColor = true;
            super.initializationComplete();
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%" radiusX="5" radiusY="5">
        <s:fill>            
            <s:SolidColor color="#d1d3d4" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

</s:SparkSkin>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't have quite the desired effect:

[image: bad fill screen shot]

Instead of the bar being flush with the track, there's a margin, and the rounded border gets cut off.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please show more code, you're not showing everything (particularly the problem area)

Comment: Huh? That's all there is, aside from the progressBar declaration itself. I'll put that and the track skin in too though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to setting the `barSkin` property, set the `maskSkin` property to the same value as `barSkin`:

You can assign this skin the same way as others in your code:

```
<mx:ProgressBar id="progressBar" name="progressBar" top="40" left="10" width="480" height="25"
    label="" labelWidth="0"
    trackSkin="Skins.ProgressBar.TrackSkin"
    maskSkin="Skins.ProgressBar.BarSkin"
    barSkin="Skins.ProgressBar.BarSkin" />
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what assigning this skin would look like? I'm very new to Flex and haven't delved in to programmatic skins yet. For example, is this done in the MXML markup or in code?

Comment: I've added that snipped to my answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Where does `MyMaskSkin` come from? Do I have to do my own implementation of ProgressMaskSkin?

Comment: Yes, you should implement it by yourself. I've added my implementation into my answer. Note I've not tested code above so please debug it yourself :)))

Comment: Excellent. I've made some adjustments to your code to make it flush with the track, but it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Even better: it's not actually necessary to use ProgrammaticSkin - simply reusing my existing bar skin for the mask skin achieves the exact same affect, and allows the color and radius to be set using the markup as well. Hope you don't mind, but I've updated your answer accordingly.